# Sequelize.js node.js many to many association

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize node.js module to form schema in Postgres sql

I Have following two schema of Project and my users.

**Project**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var project = sequelize.define('project', {
        description: DataTypes.STRING
    },{
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                project.hasMany(models.myusers,{through:"project_persons"});
            }
        }
    });

    return project;
};
```

**myusers**

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        var myusers = sequelize.define('myusers', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    },{
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                myusers.hasMany(models.project,{through:"project_persons"});
            }
        }
    });

    return myusers;
};
```

i have trying to form a many to many relationship. When i run application third table "project_person is created".

index.js (routes) i have the following code

```
models.myusers.create({
        description:"newuser"
    }).success(function(user) {
        var project1;
        var project2;

        models.project.create({
            description:"p1"
        }).success(function(p1){
            console.log("Project 1 created");
            project1 = p1;
        });
         models.project.create({
            description:"p2"
        }).success(function(p2){
            console.log("Project 2 created");
            project2 = p2;
        });

       user.setProjects([project1,project2]).success(function() {
                console.log("CREATION SUCESS");
       });
    });
```

give me following error on the screen

> /home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many-double-linked.js:151
>   foreignIdentifier] = ((targetKeys.length === 1) ? unassociatedObject[targetKey
>                                                                       ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at /home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many-double-linked.js:151:88
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at module.exports.HasManyDoubleLinked.injectSetter (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many-double-linked.js:147:38)
>       at instance.(anonymous function).success.proxy.events (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js:317:39)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.emit (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:107:33)
>       at null. (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/has-many-double-linked.js:74:63)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.emit (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:107:33)
>       at emitter.query.success.error.proxy.events (/home/hassan/Desktop/node/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:890:19)
>   24 Apr 10:31:47 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

can any body tell where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is an async library and because of that you must use callbacks. This should work as you expect:

```
models.myusers.create({ description: "newuser" }).success(function(user) {
  models.project.create({ description: "p1" }).success(function(project1) {
    console.log("Project 1 created");
    models.project.create({ description: "p2" }).success(function(project2) {
      console.log("Project 2 created");
      user.setProjects([ project1, project2 ]).success(function() {
        console.log("CREATION SUCESS");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Even better: use `complete()` and the errors (if any) properly:

```
models.myusers.create({ description: "newuser" }).complete(function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  models.project.create({ description: "p1" }).complete(function(err, project1) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Project 1 created");
    models.project.create({ description: "p2" }).complete(function(err, project2) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Project 2 created");
      user.setProjects([ project1, project2 ]).complete(function(err, association) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("CREATION SUCESS");
      });
    });
  });
});
```